Only VLC can access my Samba shares on Android
I have two samba shares in Kubuntu 24.04, one on a ext4, the other on a NTFS partition.
I want to access them from Android. There, VLC can see and access them just fine, see the files, play the media. But no file manger can. Some can show the top locations and folders but not the files, and some also say ”Access denied”.
The problem seems to be with permissions.
I see this in Samba Status:

for the one on the ext4 partition:




for the one on the NTFS partition:



/etc/samba/smb.conf contains these lines:
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

[DEPO-VIDEO]
path = /home/cip/Mounted/Samba/DEPO-VIDEO
available = yes
valid users = cip
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes

[Ntfs-Depo-VIDEOOO]
path = /home/cip/Mounted/Samba/Ntfs-Depo-VIDEOOO
available = yes
valid users = cip
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes

chmod cannot be used it seems:
chmod -v 751 /media/cip
chmod: changing permissions of '/media/cip': Operation not permitted
failed to change mode of '/media/cip' from 0750 (rwxr-x---) to 0751 (rwxr-x--x)


Have you tried sudo chmod -v 751 /media/cip? And use the "recursive" flag -R to propagate the permissions downward, although that doesn't seem the issue at this time.

@Jos - It was that simple! - Would you care to post this as answer or should I?

Go ahead and write your own answer. The clue was in the message "Could not change permissions...". A process running with user permissions attempts to change folder permissions and fails. That is a clear indication you might try that with sudo.

Based on comment by @Jos:
sudo chmod -v 751 /media/cip


Use the "recursive" flag -R to propagate the permissions downward,
although that doesn't seem the issue at this time.

